# Cannot start mariadb - timeout

Tags: raspbian, mysql

A bit of background information. I have rasbian installed on my raspberry pi 3 and i'm trying to set up mysql however it seems there is a password already set. I tried purging mariadb and mysql but I am never prompted to create the password after fresh install.

I tried resetting the password using [this](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/) and everything worked but when i got to starting mysql up again, it timed out:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
    [....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for 
    mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
    See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
     failed!
```

journalctl -xe:

```
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    -- 
    -- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
    -- 
    -- The result is failed.
    Sep 05 12:22:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered 
    failed sta
    Sep 05 12:22:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with 
    result 'tim
    Sep 05 12:22:26 raspberrypi sudo[1612]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session 
    closed f
    Sep 05 12:23:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary 
    Directorie
    -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    -- 
    -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
    Sep 05 12:23:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary 
    Directories
    -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    -- 
    -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
    -- 
    -- The start-up result is done.
    lines 1644-1666/1666 (END)
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    -- 
    -- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
    -- 
    -- The result is failed.
    Sep 05 12:22:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered 
    failed state.
    Sep 05 12:22:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with 
    result 'timeout'.
    Sep 05 12:22:26 raspberrypi sudo[1612]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session 
    closed 
    for user root
    Sep 05 12:23:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary 
    Directories...
    -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    -- 
    -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
    Sep 05 12:23:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary 
    Directories.
    -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    -- 
    -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
    -- 
    -- The start-up result is done.
    lines 1644-1666/1666 (END)
```

So my question is.. What is this journalctl -xe file saying. And also is there a default mysql root password on the Rpi3 with raspbian installed? I tried no password, 'root', 'pi', 'raspberry', 'raspberrypi' and the system password to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo mysqld_safe` that process will replay MySQL/MariaDB logs, repair tables where possible then start the server normally.

If that fails consider recovering /var/lib/mysql from the last fire security backup.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't any real data in your database then clear all in /var/lib/mysql.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

After that try again to run command `sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql` to initialize database directory.

> PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER!
>  To do
>   so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
>
> '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root password 'new-password'
>   '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root -h raspberrypi password 'new-password'
>
> Alternatively you can run:
>  '/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'
>
> which will also give you the option of removing the test databases and
>   anonymous user created by default.  This is strongly recommended for
>   production servers.